Tableview cell selected state is not correctly announced by voice over accessibility - iOS Objective C
I'm trying to add accessibility support for my iOS mobile app.
for a table view when the user clicks on the cell, we are showing tick icon at the end of the cell as shown below.
the voice should announce the selected state of the cell.

Also, I tried with below code since we are reusing the same cell the same selected state is applied for all the rows.
if(cell.selected){
        cell.accessibilityHint = @"Hidden";
    } else {
        cell.accessibilityHint = @"Visible";
    }

the value is getting change but it's getting applied for both the cells.
I'm using iOS Objective C
Any solution for this issue? Kindly help.
